# Periodic javascript in the browser for sending Http req

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

Here is the case :

I am accessing my portal and there is one button `Go to Suite`. By clicking that button i will redirected to `suite` page without login (single sign on-sso is there). Now for keeping session alive on my portal, I need to send periodically http request ( ping type ) to portal from suite page.

I have to do this through javascript.

I want to know the way by which javascript will run periodically in the background and keep sending http req to my portal, even after different different page changes in the browser.

Will setInterval works in this case ?

Plz help.Thanks.

Comment: `Will setInterval work in this case?` ...have you.. ya know... *tried* it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.

The `setInterval` method will work fine for sending requests as long as a page is loaded. However, you need to start a new interval in each page, when a page is unloaded the interval will stop running.

Comment: There are 100's of pages on the suite...how will i add it in all the pages.Will entry in the html manifest works here ?

Comment: @VJS: Hmm... manually? ;) You can put the Javascript code in a file and include it in the pages using a `script` tag. Depending on your server solution, there may be something like a master page or template where you can put the code to have it included in multiple pages.

Comment: Will making an entry in "<html manifest=\"/appsuite/abc.appcache\"><head> " abc.appcache help me ?

Comment: @VJS: As far as I can tell, that's used for caching resources, not for including resources. You can use it to make the browser cache a script file, but you still need to include the script file in the page for it to be used. (The script file would normally be cached even without the manifest.)

Comment: oh..thanks.can i put it into header (header,footer) page.That page will be always available.whats your thought ?

Comment: @VJS: If you already have some code that is included in all those pages, that sounds like a good place to put it. Be careful however so that it's not used on some pages where your script should not be used.

Comment: Thanks.Did it.Your suggestions were useful.Don't know why other people have closed this question stating its not REAL question.I think this is the real time practical issue I was facing.Thanks once again.

Comment: @VJS: I don't know what they think, but I find it clear enough. Fwiw I voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this type of construct before with great success

```
(function () {
    // your code
    ...
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: Actually the method 'setTimeout()' is the javascrpt pendant for the command 'wait' and unfortunatly is abused for such kind of task. The method 'setInterval()' is designed for this task.

Comment: The `setTimeout` will only call the callback once, not periodically. Also, it works in a single page but it will stop when you navigate to a different page.

Comment: setTimeout only calls once, but this is recursively calling itself back so no.  I didn't know about setInterval.  I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try **setTimeout()** function which is used to do tasks at periodically.

Comment: No, the `setTimeout` will run the callback function once, not periodically, you need to start another timeout from the callback to make it periodical. Also, it will stop when you navigate to a different page.